# How to insert comment block with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am programming in bash to modify a large collection of files built in C and I need to comment out segments of information (/* */).

The line reads:
*action.acroread: {APPMGR_acroread("blah.pdf");}

I want to insert a comment string "/* */" before the {APPMGR... and close it at the end of the line.

Currently I have the code

```
    for i_file in $file_list[@]}; do
        sed -i '/^*action.acroread/ s|.*|/* & */|' $i_file
        ...

    done
```

Which inserts a /* at the beginning of the line and a */ at the end of the line, commenting out the whole line.  It also prevents multiple commenting blocks from being added in case I run the script multiple times.

What I need to do is to add /* in front of {APPMGR_acroread(“blah.pdf”);} and */ at the end of the line, so the end result should look like

```
*action.acroread: /* {APPMGR_acroread(“blah.pdf”);} */
```

What I have so far is

```
sed -i ‘/^action.acroread/ s|.{APPMGR_acroread|/* & */|’ $i_file
```

This results in the following output

```
*action.acroread:/*  {APPMGR_acroread */(“blah.pdf”);}
```

In addition, running it a second time causes a second pair of comment blocks to appear

```
*action.acroread:/* /*  {APPMGR_acroread */ */(“blah.pdf”);}
```

The blah.pdf is different inside every file.  (blah.pdf, blah2.pdf, blah3.pdf, etc)

How can I modify the code to only comment block the second half of the line in addition to preventing multiple comment blocks when running the script multiple times?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` and `.` are special in `sed` POSIX regex patterns. You need to escape them.
Also, you need to capture what you need to keep and what you need to wrap with `/*...*/` into separate groups.

You can use

```sh
sed -i '/^\(\*action\.acroread[^{]*\)\(.*\)/ s||\1/* \2 */|' "$i_file"
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/W6APxC):

```
s='line...
*action.acroread: {APPMGR_acroread("blah.pdf");}
another line...'
sed '/^\(\*action\.acroread[^{]*\)\(.*\)/ s||\1/* \2 */|' <<< "$s"
## => 
#    line...
#    *action.acroread: /* {APPMGR_acroread("blah.pdf");} */
#    another line...
```

*Details*

- `/^\(\*action\.acroread[^{]*\)\(.*\)/` - finds lines that start with `*action.acroread`, and captures into Group 1 the prefix (`*action.acroread`) and then any zero or more chars other than `{`, and then captures the rest of the line into Group 2
- `s||\1/* \2 */|` - replaces the found match with Group 1, `/*` , Group 2, and  `*/`.

Comment: Thanks for the details, this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#^(\*action\.acroread: )(...)?(\{.*\})(...)?#\1/* \3 */#' file
```

If a line begins `*action.acroread:`  there may or may not be 3 characters before an opening `{` and 3 characters following a closing `}` either way replace the line with the first and the third back references, with the third back reference surrounded by `/*`  and  `*/`.